Wet spot on heat pump filter
My Trane heat pump is a couple of years old.  I have noticed that when I change the filter there is a wet spot along the edge of the filter.  First time it was at the back edge, and recent time at front edge, I think.  Should I be worried?

I agree with keshlam, however there should never be condensation on the filter.
You most likely have a situation where the condensate drain is blocked or partially blocked.
If you can, take a look inside the air return box and see if there are drips of water around. There should be none when an evaporator condensation drain system is working properly.
Take a look outside where the drain line ends, or in the basement or laundry, or wherever it terminates.  When the AC is running there should be a somewhat steady line of water trickling out.  If there isn't, there is a blockage.
Often blockages can be cleared by adding a 1/4 cup of bleach to the drain line at the air handler unit. ( exactly where is hard to say, because we cannot see you particular drain design.) Some units have a port with a cap for this type of thing, some have a safety shutoff that keep the unit from running if there is a condensate back up.  Some may be old and have nothing of the sort.
If all this is foreign and overwhelming to you, maybe you should call an AC pro. With filters getting wet, the cost is not wasted.

If you're running in cooling mode, I would expect it's just condensation.
